# Port Group Cisco 2960X + HyperV or any server

Tags: cisco, switch, ieee-802.1ax, etherchannel

First of all thank you in advance trying to solve my issue.

I'm trying to Team 4 NICs on HyperV and QNAP server to my switch Cisco 2960X in order to get 4Gbps data transfer rate to backup data faster.

I have implemented some configurations found on the internet but none of them give me 4Gbps, they just show that interface's speed is 1Gbps.

```
sh int port-channel 3 status

Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Po3       QNAP EtherChannel  connected    1          a-full a-1000
```

Here is my config:

```
interface Port-channel3
 description QNAP EtherChannel
 switchport mode access

interface range GigabitEthernet1/0/9-12
 description QNAP EtherChannel
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 channel-protocol lacp
 channel-group 3 mode active
```

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all you need to know that using port channel mean you will maximum obtain one physical link speed (1G) per ***flow*** where flow means same source port and same destination port, so if you generate 2 traffic flow  you will obtain speed of two physical link and so on .

***Versification***

there are two verification methods
 1. from cisco side ***"show port-channel summary"*** if port-channel working probably you should see  GigabitEthernet1/0/9 (p) GigabitEthernet1/0/10 (p) GigabitEthernet1/0/11 (p) GigabitEthernet1/0/12(p) , if it work probably go to next step
 2. use the very helpful tool called ***Jperf*** which is setup as server as a client and can generat 1 flow or multiple flow , if you could setup it probably generate 1 flow and monitor the traffic digrame and then generate 2 or more flows and monitor , you should realize that your BW is more than 1G

[image]

if you still facing same problem , may you make use of the this linke[NIC Teaming in Windows Server 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/10/16/nic-teaming-in-windows-server-2012-do-i-need-to-configure-my-switch.aspx)

***note***
don't make any configuration on the members of the port group , just do it under the port channel it self so simply configure
 - switchport mode access
 - speed 1000
 - duplex full
under the port channel not under the interfaces

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I guess i didn't know about 1 flow per same src and dst connections.

Answer (score 4):

Link aggregation / port-channel / lacp will not allow you to have a single stream to use several interfaces.

Four different streams can use different physical interfaces, and each one could use 1Gbs (reaching 4Gbs total) but none of them will be able to achieve more than 1Gbs.

Those protocols works with an algorithm that will choose a specific interface for a specific stream (usually based on source / destination mac addresses; IP addresses etc...), so a stream is "bound" to a physical interface.